# How to get the Quaternion

Tags: quaternions

I'm trying to understand quaternions and how to convert them.
So I was tryting but couldn't get the right answer.
So my question is below.
What is the quaternion of a vector (1,0,0)
Rotated 45 degrees around (0,0,1)

Comment: If you tried, and couldn't get the right answer, what did you get, and what do you think the right answer should be?

Comment: The rotation $45^\circ=\pi/4\ rad$ around $(0,0,1)$ is represented in polar form by $e^{\pi k/8}$ (because of the way quaternions work from both sides of a vector, you use half of the angle in radians).  Now just use Euler's formula if you want to put it in $q=a_0+a_1i+a_2j+a_3k$ form.

Comment: Thx I got it now.